# How to create element from API with name from appropriate sequence?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I'd like to use EA to generate Requirement elements programatically. I need to use the same sequence numbering (REQ00000xy), as with the GUI when pressing "Auto" button in "Add Element ..." dialog in order to keep´consistent numbering for Requirement elements created either from GUI or from API.

Selecting the last used sequence number from already existing Requierement elements won't help, as it don't move the sequence number up and next Requirement created from GUI .

Is there a way to get (and properly use) the sequence number via EA API or EA SQL?

Answer (score 3):

The table you're looking for is `t_trxtypes`. This contains something like (EA's output)

> Description;NumericWeight;Notes;TRX;TRX_ID;Style;
>
> Autocount;1,00;prefix=bla;suffix=x;active=1;active_a=0;counter=126;;Class;1; ;

You're interested in the column `Notes` which holds as CSV list like

> prefix=bla;suffix=x;active=1;active_a=0;counter=126;

This is a test setting for a class which currently has the number 126. So the next created class would be named `bla126x` and the entry would change to

> prefix=bla;suffix=x;active=1;active_a=0;counter=127;

Just keep the columne `t_trxtypes.notes` in synch with your creations.

**Note** EA does not (seem to) allow direct DB access. However, it has a proven back door:

`Repository.Execute("UPDATE t_trxtypes SET Notes='prefix=bla;suffix=x;active=1;active_a=0;counter=127;' WHERE TRX_ID=<your id>")`

will do the update (replace `<your id>` with the appropriate key). Though `Execute` is undocumented it works ever since and for sure Sparx will not limit it as nowadays everyone relies on it.

As a side note: This counter is not safe. There are lots of ways (the easiest is a simple rename) to break it. You'd need some script/add-in to have regular checks your numbering is still consistent. If you rely on requirement numbering you better use an external system like, I dare to say, DOORS.

Comment: Thanks for the question. That made me find 2 issues in my Inside EA book.

Comment: Thanks for brisk answer, Thomas. But it seems I need to update the table from script, i.e. having direct connection to DB, which makes some issues to me...

Comment: The script I'm writing is generating requirements for integration from some kind of flow diagrams, helping the otherwise manual proces. That's the reason for consistency call.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, RTFM....
For elements, where sequence is defined, if you use empty name in set =AddNew() function, EA generates the sequence upon .Update(). Not earlier. So if you plan to use the generated sequence and add some description, you need to create the element with empty name first, then Update() it and after that append your description to the content of the Name field.
As easy as this.